# How can I sell my Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, licensing

I have developed an extension for Google Chrome, but if I host the app on the Chrome Web Store there are no options to monetize the extension. This, to me, is a complete missed segment of the market, as I am sure developers would love to come up with creative applications and generate revenue for them!

I can't seem to find any alternative site/marketplace that would allow me to sell this extension though. I know that Firefox is building an app store to compete with Google and other HTML5 based app stores, but that doesn't help me too much either.

Is there any way I can.

1. Host my extension on either my own server or another app marketplace?
2. Provide some type of payment gateway with licensing that prevents users from downloading
    a copy of the `.crx` and illegally distributing it?

I have a great little app that I don't want to give it away for free. Any Ideas?

Comment: Related (but not helpful): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691172/pay-for-google-chrome-extension

Comment: I know this question is out of date, but in case anyone stumbles across this you can indeed charge for extensions and apps now: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments

Answer (score 5):

Google says that the ability to [sell extensions](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/faq#faq-extensions-01) is "coming soon".  Untill then, you can always [self-host](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/hosting.html) or turn your extension into a packaged app (see Google's notes for [selling packaged apps](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/faq#faq-app-02), which are fundamentally identical to extesnions, but add an icon to the home screen.)

**EDIT**

"New" packaged apps (since the advent of `manifest_version: 2`) are quite different from extensions and have access to a completely separate set of APIs. Extensions are meant for browser interaction (manipulating tabs, cookies, history, etc.), whereas apps are meant to be closer to standalone programs.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no alternative marketplace for paid extensions.

Anyway, you can always host the extension on your own server:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/hosting.html

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate the help from everyone.  I think there would be a market for paid extensions.  Mozilla is making a market for HTML5 apps, Facebook is rolling out a Market for HTML5 apps, but nothing is up and running for Extensions or Add-Ons.

Most Extensions, like mine, provide a time saver and efficiency-play on the users experience with the web.

Efficiency is something that can always, and should always be monetized.  Part of the reason there are so many minimalistic chrome and firefox extensions is because there is no incentive for developers to build comprehensive solutions that are free.

Is there any way that if I do Host my own Extension, which I am more than capable of doing so, that I could put something in place that would prevent users from openly sharing my extension? Maybe keep the extension "unpackaged" so people couldn't just email each other the crx file and openly share it?

Another option I was thinking about would include A log-on screen where a user would have to sign up with an account and then would be given access after they paid for the plugin online.  Is there any wayto incorporate that Log-On information into the plugin?

Thoughts?